# Postgresql: Get pg_stat_statments.calls but per PID

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to collect information about a particular query, namely `select 1` (or more globally, any `select ?`), and I need to know which application is issuing it the most. I know that I can get the total number of calls from `pg_stat_statements`, which is the total count, and I can also get which process is issuing it through `pg_stat_activity`, but I am not sure how I can combine this info to tell which process is issuing it the most. Any ideas?

I can't see a possibility for a join because the `pg_stat_statments` appears to coalesce all this data across all processes. If I can't use these tables, any others I can use before I can run some other form of profiling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pg_stat_statement` cannot produce this kind of information.

You'd have to set `log_statement = all`, then you get all these statements (and all others) in the log. Make sure that you have `%p` in your `log_line_prefix`.

Be careful: logging all statements can bring a busy server down. In PostgreSQL v12, you can set `log_transaction_sample_rate` to log only a certain sample of transactions, then you can estimate the total count.

Comment: Thank you Laurenz. I don't think we can log that much and we are still in 9.6. Will bash a few things together.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by asking, why do you think you need this in the first place?

Since you can't log all statements and can't use the random sampling logging facility, I think the next step would be to set up a loop which frequently samples pg_stat_activity (not attempting to join it to pg_stat_statements).  It is not ideal.  If you restrict the sample to where state='active', then you are likely to capture very few things in your sample.  (But that just re-enforces the first question, why do you need to do this in the first place?).  If you don't restrict it like that, then what you are capturing is not how often they execute the query, but how long they wait between executing that query and then doing something else.

If you go this route, you will probably need to use a regular expression to capture the query string, as pg_stat_activity does not normalize it.  You might get it with `?` or with `$1` or with a literal number, in a variety of cases, and with white space variants and with or without newlines and with or without a terminating semicolon.  But any given piece of software is likely to always use the same spelling.

Comment: Indeed, and the reason I need it to understand which client issues them the most. For instance Rails uses them when it attempts to reap dead connections, while Heroku uses them for health checks. We cannot be sure if Heroku is agressive or if Rails is leaking connections without understanding which client is issuing them more aggressively (we are seeing north of 350 per second, which Heroku confirms is not what they do).

Comment: @Wael Permanently leaked connections at least should be easy, they will accumulate in pg_stat_activity, where you can get at their application_name and their client_addr.

Comment: @Wael  And if they are not permanently leaked, what fraction of your total queries/s is that 350/s?  If it is high, then you can almost certainly catch the culprit just by looking at pg_stat_activity.query.  At that rate, you should catch it in the guilty state often enough to reach solid conclusions, especially if you filter to just  things `where query_start > now() - interval '0.1 second'`